NotSupportedError - WebCrypto generateKey in k6
I'm using the k6 JavaScript API to run tests, k6 is very limited when it comes to using libraries, so to do EC cryptography I'm using k6/experimental/webcrypto:
import { crypto } from "k6/experimental/webcrypto";

export function generateKeyPair() {
    crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256"
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"],
    ).then((keypair) => {
        console.log(keypair)
    })
}

However when calling my function I get the following error:
ERRO[0009] Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError
Trying the same function in nodeJS with the @peculiar/webcrypto module yields no error:
const { Crypto } = require("@peculiar/webcrypto");

function keygenPerculiarCrypto(){
    const crypto = new Crypto();

    crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDSA",
            namedCurve: "P-256"
        },
        true,
        ["sign", "verify"],
    ).then((keypair) => {
        console.log(keypair)
    })
}

Why does the k6 version not work whereas the node version does work?
Are there any alternatives for doing EC cryptography in k6 ?

Support for ECDSA was added only recently to k6 with version 0.51, which was released on May 13:

This release brings support for asymmetric cryptography to the k6/experimental/webcrypto module. We added support of the elliptic curves algorithms ECDH (xk6-webcrypto#67) and ECDSA (xk6-webcrypto#69) algorithms along with new import/export key formats like spki and pkcs8.


Attempting to run your script with k6 0.50.0 gives the (full) error message:

ERRO[0000] Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: unsupported algorithm: ECDSA

Upgrading to k6 0.51.0 works and outputs the key pair information:

INFO[0000] {"privateKey":{"type":"private","extractable":true,"algorithm":{"key_algorithm":{"algorithm":{"name":"ECDSA"},"name":"ECDSA"},"algorithm":{"name":"ECDSA"},"name":"ECDSA","namedCurve":"P-256"},"usages":["sign"]},"publicKey":{"type":"public","extractable":true,"algorithm":{"key_algorithm":{"algorithm":{"name":"ECDSA"},"name":"ECDSA"},"algorithm":{"name":"ECDSA"},"name":"ECDSA","namedCurve":"P-256"},"usages":["verify"]}}  source=console


The v0.50.x docs for subtle.generateKey mention the following support values for the algorithm parameter:

Type: string, AesKeyGenParams or HmacKeyGenParams
The type of key to generate. Can be either a string with any of the currently supported algorithms: AES-CBC, AES-GCM, AES-CTR, and HMAC as value, or any of the AesKeyGenParams or HmacKeyGenParams objects.

Compare that to the latest (v0.51.x) docs:

Type: string, AesKeyGenParams, HmacKeyGenParams or EcKeyGenParams
Description: The type of key to generate. It can be either a string with any of the currently supported algorithms as a value or any of the generation key parameter objects.


The module is clearly marked as experimental, so expect breaking changes and fast moving development! This means its doubly important to check if the documentation version matches your deployed k6 version.

k6 version gives me this output: k6 v0.51.0 (commit/33d3caa7d1, go1.22.3, linux/amd64)

@HapaxLegomenon I run the same version. Your code (copy-pasted from your question) works for me with version 0.51.0
